# Is there a measure of model complexity?

Tags: deep-learning, models, training-datasets, sample-complexity, vc-theory

Is there a measure of model complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There are at least 2 measures of model complexity studied and used in learning theory: [VC dimension and Rademacher complexity](https://mitpress.ublish.com/ebook/foundations-of-machine-learning--2-preview/7093/29). If you're new to learning theory, you could take a look at [this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/20358/2444).

(Note: your question is not an exact duplicate of [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/17870/2444), but the VC dimension is not specific to neural networks).

Answer (score 0):

There is no "unit" to measure model complexity. However, you can take into account some key factors:

- **input dimension**
- **output dimension**
- **model length (number of layers)**: Model length describes the number of transformations on the data from input to output. A higher number of layers means more possible transformations and thus the possibility to model more complex dependencies.
- **model width (number of neurons per layer)**: Model width describes the dimensionality of the data going through a single layer. A higher number of neurons means higher information retention per layer.
- **activation functions**: Without any activation functions, even the largest model can only learn linear dependencies. Activation functions introduce non-linearity into the model and make complex dependency modeling possible.

Based on those factors, you can get a good estimate of how complex your model is. Note that a more complex model does not equal better performance per-se, they require careful fine-tuning.

To get a good estimate if your model is large enough to model your data transformations, you can train it on very little data with `batchsize=1` and no regularisation. If it completely learns the given samples, it is likely to be fitting for your entire dataset aswell.

Comment: The answer address neural network only, not model in general.